# Android : Ignoring invalid text regex in 4.0.x version

Tags: android, android-emulator, ddms, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am getting error in DDMS, when I click in logcat error it moves to DDMS screen & shows this error--

```
 [2012-06-27 17:17:12 - LogCatFilter] Ignoring invalid text regex.
 [2012-06-27 17:17:12 - LogCatFilter] Unexpected internal error near index 14
 java.util.com\
          ^
```

Why I am getting this error, tried google but dint get proper information. What should I do. Please anyone can say or give me some solutions what should I do.

Comment: see  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22019

Comment: @imrankhan .. can you say me. what should i do.I am not getting anything thier. I am gettting same error as in link.

Comment: @Rahul: i think, this is an issue which is already posted to google but i't not resolved.but wait maybe anyone help u.

Comment: @imrankhan.. Yup I too searched google.. after that I posted in stackoverflow..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys..solved the problem.. After restarting the eclipse & emulator the error has gone.. Might adb.exe was not running properly.. so was occurring that problem..

**"Failure is success if we learn from it"**